# error while deploying contract to ropsten

Tags: solidity, evm, remix, ropsten

i keep getting this error when i try deploying my contract to ropsten and the mainnet `"callback contain no result Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" can someone please help me?`

Comment: With this info is imposible help you...

Comment: add your full contract source and what steps you're doing to deploy it (remix? using metamask? web3 console in geth? etc).

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that you've mis-formatted the constructor args to your contract. Depending how / where you're deploying from, if your contract requires constructor args you'd need to specify them correctly - e.g. enclose addresses with speech marks perhaps (error implies the first character is a <).

Comment: @Sebastian i am using remix ide with metamask.

Comment: @AdamDossa my constructor has no arguments, funny enough.

Comment: ok if you dont want to share any more info then that's about as far as you'll get :/

Answer (score 1):

[image]
I met similar issue when deployed my contract to my private network and fixed it by remove .DS_Store file in build/ and build/contracts. This is an issue of Truffle. Check this [.DS_Store files cause 'truffle compile' to fail](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/452) and it can also be fixed by add a recursive search bash script.

Comment: thanks, but thing is i am not using truffle.

Comment: Truffle interact with geth through web3. Maybe this will still help you.